# How to set inbound rule for Amazon ELB based on path

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I have a set of EC2 instances and a load balancer in front of them. I set up a security group for the ELB and set an inbound rule to allow HTTP traffic from anybody.

However I would like to restrict access to a specific path (say /admin) on my EC2 instances only to requests that are coming from a source ip/range. Could I do this by setting an inbound rule? It doesn't seem like it supports this. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't set up the ingress rules in the Security Groups that way; they are not specific to HTTP and don't know anything about URLs.

The way to do this is to set up access control in your HTTP server. For example in Apache you can restrict access to a particular path in either the server config or a `.htaccess` file like this:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 1.2.3.4
```

See the documentation [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html#host) for Apache. Nginx has similar features.

Answer (score -2):

ianjs is correct, you cannot accomplish what you require with ELB and/or Security Groups.

On Amazon Web Services you can visit their AWS Marketplace and use a commercial load-balancing product such as [Shaka Technologies' Ishlangu Load Balancer ADC](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00IKNUVMG/ref=srh_res_product_title?ie=UTF8&sr=0-8&qid=1407087930067) or [F5's BIG-IP LTM](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00JL3UCQ4/ref=srh_res_product_title?ie=UTF8&sr=0-3&qid=1407088142555). These two products not only provide the ability to restrict access to specific application paths but also re-direct and re-write request and/or response traffic on the fly. This can be accomplished using each vendors traffic management controls (uControl Script for Ishlangu and iRules for F5 LTM).

I would suggest using one of these over ELB or ELB + Reverse Proxy (e.g. Apache) as suggested by ianjs. The latter solution would add more latency and complexity to your environment, whilst the former does not provide the functionality you require.

Comment: And these commercial products add zero latency and complexity? Come on. He already has a web server and just needs to restrict some paths to certain IP ranges in its configuration.

Comment: +1 to @ceejayoz. This solution even adds additional cost for no good reason in this use case.